# Running module of python package

Tags: python

I am trying to execute a package from github called [plagcomps](https://github.com/NoahCarnahan/plagcomps)

I try to execute the extrinsic_testing module using the following command:

```
python -m plagcomps.extrinsic.extrinsic_testing
```

I get an error as follows:

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named dbconstants
```

I am trying to look for this package but cant find it in using pip.

Or is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the file that produces the exception](https://github.com/NoahCarnahan/plagcomps/blob/master/extrinsic/extrinsic_testing.py#L19) (next time, please post the full traceback):

```
from ..dbconstants import username, password, dbname
...
url = "postgresql://%s:%s@%s" % (username, password, dbname)
```

It seems that it expects you to create a file named `dbconstants.py` with the following content:

```
username = '...'
password = '...'
dbname = '...'
```

Replace the dots with the information about your postgres database.

Comment: Thanks and sorry. However, I am getting a new error.
`C:\Users\dhiraj\Downloads>python -m plagcomps.extrinsic.extrinsic_testing
C:\Anaconda\python.exe: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found`
.

Comment: @DhirajEadara: I don't know much about Windows, sorry.